# Pandas select rows with values are present for all elements in array

Tags: python, pandas

Firstly the title of the post may not do justice to the question, so my humble apologies for this.

Here is the question:

| Date | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-11 | 3 | 3 |
| 2024-3-11 | 4 | 5 |
| 2024-03-12 | 3 | 3 |
| 2024-3-12 | 4 | 5 |
| 2024-3-12 | 5 | 5 |
| 2024-03-13 | 3 | 3 |
| 2024-3-13 | 4 | 5 |
| 2024-3-13 | 5 | 2 |
| 2024-3-14 | 5 | 5 |

Type = [3,4,5]

Is there a simple way for me to, in Pandas, create a new DF from the above one where the data is only present if the date has values for all the elements in the list ?
Meaning the reusltant DF should only contain data for date 12,13 since the original DF has values for elements in the Type array ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set), aggregate with [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)+[`issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) and filter with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)+[boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
Type = {3,4,5}

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

keep = df.groupby('Date')['Type'].agg(Type.issubset)

out = df[df['Date'].isin(keep.index[keep])]
```

Variant with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html):

```
Type = {3,4,5}

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

out = df[df.groupby('Date')['Type'].transform(Type.issubset)]
```

Output:

```
        Date  Type  Value
2 2024-03-12     3      3
3 2024-03-12     4      5
4 2024-03-12     5      5
5 2024-03-13     3      3
6 2024-03-13     4      5
7 2024-03-13     5      2
```

Intermediates:

```
# keep
Date
2024-03-11    False
2024-03-12     True
2024-03-13     True
2024-03-14    False
Name: Type, dtype: bool

# df['Date'].isin(keep.index[keep])
# or
# df.groupby('Date')['Type'].transform(Type.issubset)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8    False
Name: Type, dtype: bool
```